# Input Checkbox Laravel 7

Tags: laravel

I need to use an input checkbox in a form. But I don't understand how to make sure that if the field is check it sends a value of 1, if it is not checked it sends a value of 2.

Can someone help me?
The form is for a new submission, not an edit form or anything else.

```
<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="private">

if($request->has('private')){
            $questions->private = 1;
        }else{
            $questions->private = 2;
        }
```

Comment: If you uncheck and submit, then it won't pass with request. So on your controller you can check it with `isset()`. Post some code, that you have tried

Comment: Try this as condition `if(isset($request->private)) { $questions->private = 1; } else { $questions->private = 1; }`

Comment: Do they both have a value of 1?

Comment: Opps, my mistake, the second will be `$questions->private = 2;`

Comment: I think, mistake here `$questions->private = 1;` try with `$questions->private = "1";` under quatation

Comment: Perfect, it works, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$private = isset($request->private) ? 1 : 2;
```